# giraph1.0 on CDH4 with JDK1.6

Tags: apache, hadoop, giraph

Can I install giraph1.0 on CDH4 with JDK1.6 as my default java installation?

I am getting an error something like this:
JDK1.6 version is below JDK1.7

And then the installation fails

Comment: "something like this" ? :) Can you share with us the exact error message and where it is coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giraph only works with JDK1.7. Atleast the latest version 1.0.0 which i downloaded.